# Postfix Temporary lookup failure

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server

I am trying to set up postfix, but I get a "Temporary lookup failure" error

main.cf:

```
inet_protocols = ipv4
inet_interfaces = all

queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix

myhostname = ns0.dzervas.gr
mydomain = dzervas.gr
myorigin = dzervas.gr
mynetworks_style = host
mydestination = localhost, localhost.$mydomain, $myhostname, $mydomain, mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain

virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/vhost
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_uid_maps = static:2000
virtual_gid_maps = static:2000
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/valias

smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

vmailbox:

```
dzervas@dzervas.gr      dzervas.gr/dzervas
dna@dzervas.gr          dzervas.gr/dna
dzervas@ns0.dzervas.gr  ns0.dzervas.gr/dzervas
```

valias:

```
webmaster@dzervas.gr    dzervas@dzervas.gr
hostmaster@dzervas.gr   dzervas@dzervas.gr
postmaster@dzervas.gr   dzervas@dzervas.gr
#dzervas@ns0.dzervas.gr dzervas@dzervas.gr
```

generic:

```
dzervas@dzervas.gr      root
```

telnet testing:

```
Trying <ip>...
Connected to <ip>.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ns0.dzervas.gr ESMTP Postfix
ehlo test.com
250-ns0.dzervas.gr
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from: testing@test.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
 rcpt to: dzervas@dzervas.gr
451 4.3.0 <dzervas@dzervas.gr>: Temporary lookup failure
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

journalctl reports:

```
May 09 15:09:22 ns0 postfix/smtpd[7754]: error: open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory
May 09 15:09:22 ns0 postfix/smtpd[7754]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
May 09 15:09:22 ns0 postfix/smtpd[7754]: connect from <client-ip>
May 09 15:09:43 ns0 postfix/smtpd[7754]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases is unavailable. open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory
May 09 15:09:43 ns0 postfix/smtpd[7754]: warning: hash:/etc/aliases lookup error for "dzervas@dzervas.gr"
May 09 15:09:43 ns0 postfix/smtpd[7754]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from <client-ip>: 451 4.3.0 <dzervas@dzervas.gr>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<testing@test.com> to=<dzervas@dzervas.gr> proto=ESMTP helo=<test.com>
May 09 15:09:52 ns0 postfix/smtpd[7754]: disconnect from <client-ip>
```

I should point out that I haven't set up the DNS records yet (dzervas.gr is not pointing my new server yet)
Also I'm on arch linux x86_64

EDIT: I created an empty /etc/aliases and then `newaliases`
new problem (in telnet):

```
rcpt to: dzervas@dzervas.gr
550 5.1.1 <dzervas@dzervas.gr>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table
```

but!:

```
rcpt to: root@localhost
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
hhahahahha
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as <some-code>
```

EDIT 2: solved the `Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table` by setting `local_recipient_maps =` in main.cf
However, now my mail to dzervas@dzervas.gr get queued! it does not go at /var/mail/vmail/dzervas.gr/dzervas/ as it should!

Comment: If you're looking to test a mailserver, a functioning DNS entry is a pretty fundamental piece. Postfix is looking to see if `dzervas.gr` is configured.. get your DNS working then test.

Comment: ok, thank you. does the setup seems correct to you?

Comment: It's awfully simple, but it's a start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `newaliases` . If /etc/aliases doesn't exist then create it first, then run `newaliases` .
Also maybe update/add `alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases` to /etc/postfix/main.cf to get rid of the other warning.
Then try again.
(If you test with telnet, you don't need working DNS).

---

2nd issue:
First remove `$myhostname, $mydomain,` from `mydestination`, since virtual domains shouldn't be listed here.
Then add (to main.cf):

```
virtual_mailbox_domains=dzervas.gr
```

Reload postfix and try again.

Comment: You were right! I created an empty /etc/aliases and then newaliases.
New problem arouse...

Comment: Edited my post .

Comment: thank you soooo much!
PS: I had to create and chown the /var/spool/mail/vmail/ directory (just for reference)

Comment: Fixed my problem after a server reboot running Sentora/zPanel panel, thanks.

Comment: thanks, issue solved in 2nd issue solution

Answer (score 22):

### mynetworks needs strict network ranges

In my case, there was a wrong ip range in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`.

```
# Wrong; Temporary lookup failure
mynetworks = 172.16.0.0/8
# OK
mynetworks = 172.16.0.0/12
```

There was an error in `/var/log/maillog` that I noticed later.

> Oct  4 13:47:54 postfix/smtpd[25056]: warning: non-null host address bits in "172.16.0.0/8", perhaps you should use "172.0.0.0/8" instead

If someone comes here from the top hit on google with searching `Temporary lookup failure`, I'd say please dubble-check your `$mynetworks` format.

Comment: Thnx, that was the solution to my problem. Also not OK: 172.16.0.1/12

Comment: Also was my issue. 172.19.0.1/24 is not OK either.

Comment: This, 127.0.0.1/8 is what got me.

Comment: yes, this problem just bit me in the ass, and while searching for the solution after the fact, I came across this answer.

Answer (score 1):

My 5 cents:

I did changed main.conf, but I forgot to reload postfix.

after reload it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If your `main.cf` contains a hash path like so:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains
```

(containing `mydomain.tld OK`)

...make sure to create the expected `/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.db` using `postmap virtual_mailbox_domains`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the cause of the "Temporary lookup failure" problem was that I started using a [pcre](https://www.postfix.org/PCRE_README.html) table in my configuration:

```
mydestination = $myhostname,
   pcre:/etc/postfix/local-host-patterns,
   $mydomain, 
   localhost.$mydomain,
   localhost
```

It turned out that I had never installed the `postfix-pcre` package. In RHEL-style distributions, this can be installed with

```
dnf install postfix-pcre
```